# Anyone help me to create a wordpress progress bar and text or image show after 100%?

Tags: wordpress, bar-chart, progress

After completing the progress bar up to 100% then hide the progress bar and then show an image or link or button.

Please share your expertices.

Comment: Hello, please explain further where and what exactly you want to do.
For example, you want to have a progress bar on the posts page or a loading

Comment: I want to progress or a loading bar. after the complete the progress bar up to 100% then show the download image. Mainly, If visitors want to download they need to wait for 30s or 60s for the download page. Please check the image:  https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/27729531?key=96075e723526846df73fd346fcd96725

Answer (score 0):

I made something
You can see the example in [this link](https://valahaa.com/devops/)
And that my code is as follows:

html code:

```
<div class="contet">

<div class="panel panel-default counter-panel card">
    <div class="panel-body text-center card-body" id="__procon">
        <div id="wpdm_lazy_download_" class="progress progress-striped active">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped  progress-bar-animated"
                 role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
                <span class="sr-only">Please Wait...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wpdmw8" class="panel-footer card-footer">Please Wait...</div>
</div>
```

css code:

```
.contet {
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: 50px auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00000017;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 50px;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.counter-panel {
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

.counter-panel .panel-body {
    padding: 15px;
}

.counter-panel .progress {
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0;
}

.counter-panel .circle {
    font-family: 'Courier Prime', monospace;
    font-size: 40pt;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.counter-panel .panel-footer {
    font-family: 'Courier Prime', monospace;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
    from {
        background-position: 1rem 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
}

@keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
    from {
        background-position: 1rem 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
}

.progress {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    height: 1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.progress-bar {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #4a8eff;
    transition: width 0.6s ease;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    .progress-bar {
        transition: none;
    }
}

.progress-bar-striped {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-size: 1rem 1rem;
}

.progress-bar-animated {
    -webkit-animation: progress-bar-stripes 1s linear infinite;
    animation: progress-bar-stripes 1s linear infinite;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    .progress-bar-animated {
        -webkit-animation: none;
        animation: none;
    }
}

.btn {

    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4a8eff;
    border-color: #4a8eff;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    display: block;
}

.card-footer:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 calc(0.25rem - 1px) calc(0.25rem - 1px);
}
.counter-panel .panel-footer {
    font-family: 'Courier Prime', monospace;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.panel-footer {
    color: #555555;
}
```

jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#wpdm_lazy_download_ .progress-bar").animate({width: "100%"}, -1000, function () {
        //jQuery.cookie("wpdm_lazy_download_'.$lazy_download_id.'","-1", { expires: 1, path: "/" });
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getMilliseconds();

        setTimeout(
            function () {
                $('#wpdmw8').html('Your Download is Ready!');
                $('#__procon').html("<a href='' class='btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg'>Download</a>");

            }, 1000);


    });
});
```

Wherever it was difficult to tell me to check.

Comment: please check that, https://try.wpdownloadmanager.com/addons/preparing-download/?pack=9063366e3ba3efafeddfb78e4e422c62

Comment: @Md.AbdurRahman Hello again
I edited the code, check again